# "Cannot find a valid peer process to connect to" VMware Workstation 10.0.1 while booting a VM

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I've just installed the VMware Workstation 10.0.1, but when I try to boot a virtual machine (I've created a new guest and I also have a virtual disk image of another VM), it doesn't start to run and I get this error: **"Cannot find a valid peer process to connect to"**. I've googled around but didn't find a solution to the problem. I am using Windows 7 64 bit. 
I also have VirtualBox installed (maybe VMware goes in conflict with VirtualBox?).

What should I do? I need those virtual machines to run.

Comment: What type of virtual disk image do u have ?

Comment: It's a .vmdk disk image. I have re-installed the VMware Workstation 8.0.3. I have linked the disk to this older version and the VM starts to run but suddenly I got stuck with a black screen and a blinking message "**Loading darwin/x86**" (I am trying to install a MAC OS X Mavericks 10.9 disk image)...

Is there a way to resolve?

Answer (score 2):

If the above solution didn't work, just restart your machine (Physical machine) and try booting again.

Comment: This question is very very old. I don't even remember whether I solved or not... And I do not have VMWare Workstation installed anymore...

Comment: I faced the same problem today and this worked. This could help someone else.

Comment: I faced the similar problem. I just deleted all the recent .lock and .vmem files, then restarted the host. This fixed my problem.

Comment: Worth a try. Worked for Fusion 8 on El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to "allow" the VMware system extension (macOS warned me about this being blocked on install, but I ignored it).

In brief: System Preferences > Security and Privacy > General > Click "Allow" on the "VMware blocked" message

See accepted answer here for further details: [https://superuser.com/questions/1256489/how-to-fix-vmware-fusion-pro-10-cannot-find-a-valid-peer-process-to-connect-to](https://superuser.com/a/1258547/172686)

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if this is really a solution but in my case it worked.
I had to go to the "Virtual Machine Library" and Double-click the VM that's throwing the error and that fixed it.